# Python class: Why can't I use the method len() inside __eq__(self, other)?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, oop, variable-length

https://gist.github.com/rjurney/1e8454af8e44312d02d7

```
class FrozenSortedTuple:
  """A frozenset that cares about order of tuples. And is not actually frozen."""
  def __init__(self, vals):
    if type(vals) not in [list, set, tuple]:
      raise Exception('Value not a list or set')
    self.vals = list(vals)

  def __eq__(self, other):
    if len(self.vals) != len(other):
      return False
    if type(self.vals) != type(other):
      return False
    if type(other) not in [list, set, tuple]:
      return False
    other_list = list(other)
    for i,item in enumerate(self.vals):
      if item != other_list[i]:
        return False
    return True
```

Called in iPython:

```
In [2]: a = ['a','b']

In [3]: b = ['b','a']

In [4]: c = ['a','b']

In [5]: a == b
Out[5]: False

In [6]: FrozenSortedTuple(a)
Out[6]: <__main__.FrozenSortedTuple instance at 0x103c56200>

In [7]: fa = FrozenSortedTuple(a)

In [8]: fb = FrozenSortedTuple(b)

In [9]: fa == fb
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-317181571e4d> in <module>()
----> 1 fa == fb

<ipython-input-1-ef99f0af5061> in __eq__(self, other)
     15 
     16   def __eq__(self, other):
---> 17     if len(self.vals) != len(other):
     18       return False
     19     if type(self.vals) != type(other):

AttributeError: FrozenSortedTuple instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

I'm confused.

Comment: The problem isn't "you can't call `len` inside `__eq__`". The problem is "you can't call `len` anywhere at all" because you never implented it for this class. `len(fa)` would fail in the main scope the same way.

Comment: Why would all global functions disappear inside a class?

Comment: OH! I get it. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, no I don't. I'm calling len() not on self, or an instance of the ... yes I am. Ok, thanks! Can you make the answer in an answer and not a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, based on the other answers, what i wanted is this:

```
class FrozenSortedTuple:
  """A frozenset that cares about order of tuples. And is not actually frozen."""
  def __init__(self, vals):
    if type(vals) not in [list, set, tuple]:
      raise Exception('Value not a list or set')
    self.vals = vals

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.vals)

  def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.vals)

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    return list(self.vals)[key]

  def __eq__(self, other):
    if len(self) != len(other):
      print "len(self)"
      return False

    for i,item in enumerate(self.vals):
      if item != other[i]:
        return False
    return True

  def __str__(self):
    str_val = str()
    for val in self:
      str_val += str(val)
    return str_val

  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(str(self))
```

Tests:

```
# FrozenSortedTuple Tests
a = ['a','b']
b = ['b','a']
c = ['a','b']

fa = FrozenSortedTuple(a)
fb = FrozenSortedTuple(b)
fc = FrozenSortedTuple(c)

fa == fb
fa == fc
fa == ['a','b']
fa == ['b','a']
fa == ('a','b')
fa == ('b','a')

a = set([fa, fb, fc])
b = set([fa, fb, fc])
c = set([fa, fc, fb])
a == b
b == c
fa in a
fb in b

d = set([fb])
fa in d
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to directly compare the structure and contents of the values of two FrozenSortedTuples, change all your instances of `other` to `other.vals`.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if len(self.vals) != len(other.vals):
      return False
    if type(self.vals) != type(other.vals):
      return False
    if type(other.vals) not in [list, set, tuple]:
      return False
    other_list = list(other.vals)
    for i,item in enumerate(self.vals):
      if item != other_list[i]:
        return False
    return True
```

Of course, this will fail to work if `other` isn't a FrozenSortedTuple. For instance, `fa == 23` won't work because the number 23 doesn't have a "vals" attribute.

Comment: Or just implement `def __len__(self): return len(self.vals)`.

Comment: Yes, but then `if type(self.vals) != type(other)` will fail to work as expected, and so on for all his other conditionals.

Comment: Yes, the rest of the code of course would need to be adapted accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The way you define `__eq__(self, other)`, equality can only be achieved when other is *an instance of* the type you are wrapping, i.e. list, set, or tuple.  You trigger the error by comparing two instances of `FrozenSortedTuple`.  The error message tells you that len() cannot be invoked on such an instance, and that is because you have not defined the method `__len__(self)` in your class.

If you define `__len__()` for your class, it will work.  See [the Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) (this links to the 2.7 docs, but it should work the same in Python 3.x)
Alternatively, you could compare `len(self.vals) == len(other.vals)` to compare `FrozenSortedTuple` instances.